# Handle Range based queries

Tags: key-value, aerospike

We came across a case, where we want to retrieve data from a time series. Let say we have time based data : [“t1-t2” : {data1}, “t2-t3” : {data2}, “t3-t4”:{dat3}]

With the above kind of data, we would want to look up exact data w.r.t time. For example, for a given time t1.5, the data has to come as data1, and for t2.6 it should come as data2.

To solve the above problem, we are planning to store the data in a sorted map in aerospike as mentioned below {“t1”:{data1}, “t2”:{dat2}, “t3”: {data3}}

When a client asks for t1.5, we must return data1. To achieve this, we implemented a UDF at the server level to do a binary search for the nearest and lowest value for the given input (i.e t1.5), which will return t1 's value ,i.e data1.

Is there a better way of achieving the same, as it incurs cost at server level for every request. Even UDF to do a binary search requires loading all the data in memory, can we avoid it?

We are planning to use a Aerospike for this. Is there a better data store to handle such queries..?

Answer (score 1):

Thinking aloud… Storing t1-t2, t2-t3 is redundant on t2. Just store t1, t2 is inferred from next key:value. { t1:data, t2:data, …} - store key sorted (map policy) You must know max difference between any ‘t1’ and ‘t2’ Build secondary index on MAPKEY and type numeric (this essentially does the bulk of the sort work for you upfront in the RAM) Search for records where t between t-maxdiff and t+maxdiff ==> a set of few records and pass these to your UDF. Invoke UDF on these few records subset to return the data. This will be a very simple UDF. Note: UDFs are limited to 128 concurrent executions at any given time.

Comment: Correction: "limited to 128" is incorrect, "performance degrades when  concurrent executions exceed 128" is more appropriate because memory has to be allocated on the fly.

Comment: ... and that is 128 concurrent invocations of the same UDF per node.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. First, you should be inserting into a [K-ordered map](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-map.html#element-ordering), where the key is the timestamp (in millisecond or second or another resolution). The value would be a map of the attributes.

To get back any range of time you'd use a [get_by_key_interval](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-map.html) (for example the Python client's [`Client.map_get_by_key_range`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.map_get_by_key_range)). You can figure out how to build the range but it's simply *all between two timestamps*.

Don't use a UDF for this, it is not going to perform as well or scale as the native map/list operations would.